# LINQ vs context.entity.Where()

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Are these two blocks exactly the same? Does one have any advantage over the other?

```
        using (var context = new TRANSITEntities())
        {
            var result = context.Table1.Where(c => c.UserCode == "123");
        }


        using (var context = new TRANSITEntities())
        {
            var result = from c in context.Table1
                         where c.UserCode == "123"
                         select c;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly the same.

You can verify this yourself by looking at the ToString()

```
    string query1String, query2String;
    using (var context = new TRANSITEntities())
    {
        var result = context.Table1.Where(c => c.UserCode == "123");
        query1String = result.Expression.ToString();
    }


    using (var context = new TRANSITEntities())
    {
        var result = from c in context.Table1
                     where c.UserCode == "123"
                     select c;
        var query2String = result.Expression.ToString();
    }

    Assert.AreEqual(query1String, query2String);
```

It should also be noted that `result` is NOT actually a result. It's a non-executed/enumerated `IQueryable`. Meaning it's like a SQL statement that hasn't been run yet (sort of). If you were to do

```
    var t1 = result.ToArray()
    var t2 = result.ToArray()
```

then the query would actually be executed twice. `t1` and `t2` are the REAL results (an in memory array)...not `result`. In other words, `result` should really be named `query` And further, the example you have above will never work...because if you call `ToArray` on the result outside of the `using` block, it will fail...because you can't run the query once the context is disposed:

```
    using (var context = new TRANSITEntities())
    {
        var result = context.Table1.Where(c => c.UserCode == "123");
    }
    // throws exception:
    var array = result.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

<s>Well the first selects from `context.Table1`, the second selects from `context.LINTE`. So they select from totally different collections.</s>

Also the first selects on a UserCode column and the second on a CodeUsager column..

Apart from that (*is the first just a translation of the second and you forgot to translate the second*) the code is the same. The C# compiler will just translate the second query into the first one and they will behave identically.

Answer (score 3):

They're exactly the same. The compiler converts the query syntax to the lambda expression version before it resolves any methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to select from different tables then it is different.

But if the tables are same then it is just the representation different.

There is no difference it is just the preference which way you like to code.

All the linq queries are converted to Lambda before creating the sql representation.

Answer (score 1):

From Julia Lermans' book Programming Entity Framework:

> The MSDN documentation says, “In general, we recommend query syntax
>   because it is usually simpler and more readable; however, there is no
>   semantic difference between method syntax and query syntax.”*
>   Therefore, using one over the other is a matter of style and personal
>   choice.